# Why the select2 is not populating the control with the latest data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using this for a progressive search.

Technically it works but the control is not getting filled with the data being returned.

```
 $("#selUser").select2({
            ajax: {
                url: "/M01EngineeringData/GetFunctionalLocations",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        search: params.term // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                   // alert(response);
                    return {
                        results: response

                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });
```

Html:

```
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <span class="Label_small_bold">Progressive Search :</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <select id='selUser' style='width: 200px;'>
                                    <option value='0'>- Search user -</option>
                                </select>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetFunctionalLocations(string search)
        {
            try
            {
                return Json(enggDataService.GetFunctionalLocations(search) , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

This controller is returning data in correct format.

```
["Test Func Location","Test Func Location","Test Func Location"]
```

but the selUser control is not getting populated with the data, why?

Answer (score 0):

you need to return something like this by looping your response
{
    id: "value attribute",
    text: "label attribute",
    element: HTMLOptionElement
}
refer -
https://select2.org/options